# Building tree diagram

Tags: shell-script

Suppose I have a program P11 in a directory; it calls 2 other programs P21 & P22.
Each of P21 & P22 call 2-2 other programs.

i.e.

```
Level-1:           |--------------P11-------------|
Level-2:  |--------P21----------|    |----------P22----------|...
Level-3:  P31                 P32    P33                   P34...
       .                   .      .                     .
       .                   .      .                     .
```

Just like a tree diagram having 100s of levels, 100s of nodes at each level and 1000s of nodes in total.

I need a shell script which will give me such a tree structure.

e.g. The shell script program is – ‘`MYPGM.sh`’.

It takes a parameter at runtime. We can provide a program name here e.g. P11.
And the script gives such a tree diagram.

Not necessary that the output structure should be in such a diagram like format as given above.
We can use indexing or anything you suggest.
e.g. The output file could be as –

```
1. P11
1.1 P21 - 1.2 P22
1.1.1 P31 - 1.1.2 P32 – 1.2.1 P33 – 1.2.2 P34
```

i.e. Every program's index = it's parent's index + "." + its serial number in that parent program.

Just the thing is – the number of levels & number of nodes in each level is unknown, but very large.

The program syntax used to call another program is as below.:

CALL "CHILD_PGM_NAME"

Command to find the children programs in a given program is as below.:

```
 egrep '^CALL| CALL ' $pgm_name > call_output | cut -d'"' -f2 call_output > call_output_cut | cat call_output_cut
```

I am stuck at - how to loop this command to get the above stated output file.

Can anybody suggest something?

Comment: Ahem.. Those pipes are meaningless. Did you mean `;` instead? And is it guaranteed to be a tree?  For example, P22 may not call P21?

Comment: Do you need this as text? If you want to *see* this data to understand it, have you considered graphviz (e.g., `dot`)?

Comment: Have you considered `ps f` and `ps -H`?

Comment: Also have a look at `pstree`.

Comment: You should provide the example input that leads to your example output.

Comment: Example input is already given as a tree diagram. And, the language syntax of calling a child program from parent program is also ginen, which is -

Answer (score 3):

For this problem I suggest awk, python, perl or similar. The following starting point is a perl script that enqueues the "programs" if not yet visited. The output is in graph-viz (as suggested by @derobert).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "digraph{\n rankdir=LR \n";

my %visited = ();
while(<>){                               # for all lines in all files in @ARGV

  $visited{$ARGV}=1;                     # $ARGV = current file

  if(/\bCALL\s*"(.+?)"/) {
      print "$ARGV -> $1;\n" ;
      push @ARGV,$1  unless $visited{$1};
      $visited{$1}=1;
  }
}

print "}\n";
```

usage:

```
perl calltree p1 > x.dot
dot -Tpdf -o x.pdf x.dot
```

or (thank you @derobert)

```
dot -Tx11 x.dot
```

to view the graph immediately.

As @muru pointed out, typically  this is not tree.

Comment: You may also want to point out `dot -Tx11` to view immediately instead of making a PDF.

Answer (score 1):

@JJoao's way is definitely the one to use. However, I wrote this very inefficient script, that might be of interest:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

SRC_DIR="/path/to/programs"
TMP_DIR="/tmp/tree"
declare -A FUNCS

iterate ()
(
    program="$1"
    FUNCS["$program"]="$TMP_DIR/$program"
    mkdir "${FUNCS[$program]}"
    grep -Po '(?<=\bCALL ")[^"]*' "$SRC_DIR/$program" | while read child
    do
        if [[ -n ${FUNCS[$child]} ]]
        then
            ln -s "${FUNCS[$child]}" "${FUNCS[$program]}/$child"
        else
            iterate "$child"
        fi
    done
)

[[ -n $1 ]] && { iterate "$1"; tree -dlo call-graph.html -H "$TMP_DIR" "$TMP_DIR"; }
rm -rf "$TMP_DIR"
```

It creates a directory *tree*, with each directory representing a function, containing symbolic links to the other directories/functions it calls. The `tree` program is naturally good at drawing trees (the `-l` option follows symbolic links unless recursion is detected, `-o` generates HTML output).

Of course, you should ideally be looking at Call Graph Generators for your language. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517589/tools-to-get-a-pictorial-function-call-graph-of-code) lists some for C, perhaps you might be able to find one which supports your language.